Given $f(z)=\frac{z^2-3iz}{(z^2+9)(z^2+4z+13)^2}$, calculate the integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z)dz$

Given $f(z)=\frac{z^2-3iz}{(z^2+9)(z^2+4z+13)^2}$,

find all singularity points and sort them (poles and so on..),

calculate the integral $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z)dz$.



For the first part:

the denominator: $z^2+9=(z-3i)(z+3i)$ and $z^2+4z+13=(z-(-2-3i))(z-(-2+3i))$
the numerator: $z^2-3iz=z(z-3i)$.

From here I got that $-2\pm3i$ is a pole of order 2, $z=-3i$ is pole of order 1, and $z=3i$ is a removable point (not sure if this is the correct translation).
For the second part:
I want to use the residue theorem. For it I wanted to do $2i\pi(Res(f,3i)+Res(f,-2+3i)+Res(f,-2-3i)+Res(f,-3i))$
but in the book they only did $2i\pi Res(f,-2+3i)$.
Why is that?
This is my main question: I do not understand why not take all the residues.

@AnneBauval Thank you I did not notice the typo
and thanks for fixing my calculation but why not calculate all the residues?

"I want to use the residue theorem": please review it before posting such a question.

@AnneBauval Isn't it removable point(again not sure if this is the correct term in English sorry about that) because we have $(z-3i)$ on the numerator and $(z-3i)$ on the denominator as well? and so the residue will be zero?
I did double check I guess it is a typo from the book

Thanks so much.

Your post is essentially a duplicate of, for instance, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832407.

Hint: Choose the upper semicircle contour with radius $R$ and apply the residue theorem. Note that for $f$ we have
$$\deg(\text{denominator})-\deg(\text{numerator})\geq2,$$
then you can easily show that the integral along the arc vanishes as $R$ tends to infinity, leaving alone the integral you want.
Therefore what actually matters is the residues in the upper half-plane.
